# IS it possible to use 2 different record sources for a drop down box on an access form?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Hello I am trying to use a drop down box on my form that will display two different record sources based on an if statement and can't get it to work. Is this possible??

Basically I want to show the codes and descriptions for the DX_Codes table If the date is less than 10/1/2015 and show the DX_Codes_ICD_10 if it is greater than or equal to 10/1/2015.  The date is also a field on the same form.

```
IIf(Me.from_date < #10/1/2015#, 
SELECT DX_Codes.dx_code, DX_Codes.dx_code_desc FROM DX_Codes ORDER BY DX_Codes.dx_code, 
SELECT DX_Codes_ICD10.dx_code, DX_Codes_ICD10.dx_code_desc FROM DX_Codes_ICD10 ORDER BY DX_Codes_ICD10.dx_code);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use VBA to manage a RowSource of a control like a combobox. Place the below behind some event trigger, possibly related with the `from_date` control.

```
If Me.from_date < #10/1/2015# Then
    Me.ComboBoxName.RowSource = "SELECT DX_Codes.dx_code, DX_Codes.dx_code_desc" _
                                 & " FROM DX_Codes ORDER BY DX_Codes.dx_code;"
    Me.ComboBoxName.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Else
    Me.ComboBoxName.RowSource = "SELECT DX_Codes_ICD10.dx_code, DX_Codes_ICD10.dx_code_desc" _
                                 & " FROM DX_Codes_ICD10 ORDER BY DX_Codes_ICD10.dx_code);"
    Me.ComboBoxName.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
End If
```